# How do I remove modifiers from the modifier stack if they don't have an 'x' button?

Tags: modifiers, interface

Some modifiers, notably particle system do not have any "minus" sign that allows for them to be removed. I want to keep the fluid settings but remove the particle system and redo it as it has gotten messed up trying something. But I can't remove it.

My workaround at the moment is to save the settings and delete the whole model and reimport it - starting again simply to remove modifiers I don't want.

Any idea how to remove unremovable modifiers?

Comment: It's written there in the stack under the modifier's name that options for the modifier are in the physics or particle systems tab (depending on the modifiers, for Fluid and Particle system repsectively).

Answer (score 3):

Particle systems are controlled in the Particle systems tab.
Where you can add or remove different systems.

Click on the icon to open the tab here

[image]

Or click on the tab for particles directly

[image]

To delete a particle system click on the minus sign in the upper right.

[image]